# Iterating over rows or columns of 2D array with Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I need to iterate over the rows of an Eigen 2D array.

[The documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSTL.html) indicates that this is be possible and provides a code snippet:

```
ArrayXXi A = ArrayXXi::Random(4,4).abs();
for(auto row : A.rowwise())
  std::sort(row.begin(), row.end());
```

However when I try to compile this code I get the following error:

```
error: invalid range expression of type 'Eigen::VectorwiseOp<Eigen::Array<int, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1>';
no viable 'begin' function available
    for(auto row : A.rowwise())
                 ^ ~
```

This is the only problem I have so far with the library. I am compiling with clang 7 , but I get a similar error with GCC. I tried to include every header from the library with no chance.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: In your link, it is supported since version 3.4. But it looks like 3.4 is not released yet?

Comment: Question... What is returned by the method abs()? What type it is? What does it holds? Is it possible for you to add some breakpoints and some watchers?

Comment: @acarlstein abs() just return the absolute value of the matrix, it is essentially useless in that exemple, it's just showoff from the doc.

Comment: @HanjoungLee Thanks for noticing, it wouldn't have crossed my mind that the official documentation would refer to features not implemented yet in stable release... this is most likely the problem here. Unfortunately the dev branch doesn't compile on my project.

Comment: The `devel` in `dox-devel` should give a hint that this refers to the **devel**opment branch of Eigen. The documentation for the latest stable is at https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/ (and does not have that feature).

If you have code that compiles with the current stable but not with the devel-branch, it might be worth reporting that as a bug: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/ (or ask a question at SO, if you are unsure whether you are misusing something)

Comment: URL shortening made me miss that information. Thank you for the link, I will fill a bug report for the problem I have with the devel branch.